# How I have to use the allowedGridTypes feature for gridelements dependencies in TYPO3?

Tags: grid, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I am using Gridelements 7.0.4 and TYPO3 7.6.2 and want to set some dependencies with the allowedGridTypes feature, but I don't know which string, name or id I have to set. On the documentation page ([gridelements documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/gridelements/Chapters/GridTsSyntax/Index.html)) I can see that's strings like the following are used and I read "You can use a comma separated list of Grid names", but where can I define this grid names?

```
allowedGridTypes = 2ColumnContainer,3ColumnContainer
```

I have created a system folder and inside this folder I have created all my gridelements. Furthermore I have configured for each of my gridelements a title like "Inhaltsbereich" and a grid configuration like:

```
backend_layout {
colCount = 1
rowCount = 1
rows {
    1 {
        columns {
            1 {
                name = Inhaltsbereich
                colPos = 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

So I thought the row

```
name = Inhaltsbereich
```

defines the grid name of this gridelement, but if I add the following to my backend layout:

```
backend_layout {
colCount = 1
rowCount = 1
rows {
    1 {
        columns {
            1 {
                name = Startseite
                colPos = 10
                allowed = gridelements_pi1
                allowedGridTypes = Inhaltsbereich,WeißerBereich
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

then I can't add a gridelement any more and no gridelements will be suggested any more. My typoscript looks like the following:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {

# content block
1 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
1 {
    columns {
        10 < .default
        10.wrap = <section class="container">|</section>
    }
}

# white content block
2 < .1
2 {
    columns {
        10.wrap = <section class="container white-block">|</section>
    }
}

...

}
```

So I have tried to add the ids to the allowedGridTypes field:

```
allowedGridTypes = 1,2
```

This seems to work a little bit, but not perfectly, because I can only add the gridelement with the id = 2 to the content elements of my backend layout now, but not the gridelement with id = 1. Hope someone can enlighten me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "GridTypes" you can add to the allowedGridTypes section are the IDs of the corresponding layouts. So your latest approach is correct.

Still you get only 2, since there seems to be a bug https://forge.typo3.org/issues/72569#change-292916

Should be soon in master and then be fixed with the next release of gridelements.